# Mixing PHP variables into a jquery form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm creating a 2 part log in, where the user enters their username in the first part and then random charactors of a password and pin are asked for in the second part. This works fine when I just use php and html but when I tried converting to jquery the PHP values are just not showing up. I checked by outputing a variable on its own and the variable is set but when I try any php whatsoever to the form it doesn't work :( tried different variations but no avail.
log in part 2

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is happening exactly? Do you get any errors in firebug or chrome console?

Comment: everything but the php variables is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't echoing the variables.
Try `<?$number1?>` to `<?php echo $number1; ?>` and change all variables.

Comment: i did this at first but without the "php" and it didn't work- works fine now though thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better yet try to change `<?number1?>` to `<?=$number1?>`

Comment: Iff [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is enabled (likely is but OP doesn't conclusively say)